# DomCrawler Select All Input Tags Within Form

Tags: symfony, xpath, domcrawler

I have a webpage I'm scraping form fields from (or trying at least). I'm using `Symfony2` (and `Goutte`) to do this, so I have a `$crawler` object. Here's an example of the html below:

```
<html>
<body> 
... other html stuff ...
<form method="post" action="goSomewhere">
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="123">Stuff 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked name="456">Stuff 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="789">Stuff 3</td></tr>
</body> 
</html>
```

As you can see, there's a lot of nested content. My interest is only the `<input>` tags inside the `<form></form>` tags.

I'm trying things like:

```
$query = "//form/input";
$inputs = $crawler->filterXPath($query);
```

but it doesn't seem to be getting all (and only) the input tags. I did a `->count()` and I only get like 8 as the number, when there are more like 50-100 input tags.

Can anyone help me get the correct query to do this?

---

Also, once I have that I'm interested in removing specific inputs. Is there a method in Dom`Crawler` that will let me do this? I've looked around many places and can't find much. Perhaps if I do an inverted filtering system?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `$query = "//form/input";` will only find input elements that are a direct child of the form. In your html, these inputs are grandchildren. `$query = "//form//input";` will give you all input elements that are nested inside a form element.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, the number now went from 8 to 152!